# Can Firebase used callback on embedded system

Tags: c, https, callback, firebase

Now I just get and post Firebase request through sending https request using C language.

Is there any way to use callback for this?

Because I want to get the latest data, now I just polling the https get requests. The SSL handshake may cause delay, so I want to add callback for this.

Comment: HTTP is at heart a request-response protocol. You send a request, and receive a response, in other words you have to poll. Thing like "push" notifications are not part of the core HTTP, but can be implemented using [web-sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

Comment: Same project by any chance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313119/can-firebase-used-callback-on-embedded-system

Comment: Firebase does support streaming from a REST streaming API, following the EventSource/Server-Sent Events protocol. I'm not sure if that is what you're looking for, but you can find out more here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-streaming.

Comment: If I want to use streaming to get the updated data, what should the http header filled? Thanks